# Wordpress Ajax form processing with php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I have a form on my site which is currently posting to a php file. Right now when the form is submitted it takes users to the blank php file. I want to have it post via ajax or redirect after it has processed the mail function.
Thanks!

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="formApply"  action="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/inc/sendContact.php" name="applyForm">
                <div id="col1">
                <fieldset class="col-1">
                <div class="white info-line">Want to know more? Drop us a line and we'll get right back to you.</div>
                <label class="white text-label name" for="fname">Name:</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" tabindex="1" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label class="white text-label email" for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" class="lower" name="email" id="email"  tabindex="2"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label class="white text-label phone" for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="3" maxlength="10"/>
                <div class="white text-label checker-title" id="checkererror">I am interested in:</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Office Space" /><label for="checkbox-2-1"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Office Space</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-2" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Designated Workspace" /><label for="checkbox-2-2"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Designated Workspace</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-3" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Shared Space" /><label for="checkbox-2-3"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Shared Space</div>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div id="col2">
                <fieldset class="col-2">
                <label class="white text-label note-label" for="notes">Notes:</label><br/>
                <textarea name="notes" id="notes" rows="10" cols="30" class="requiredField" tabindex="4"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" class="submitted" value="true" /><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit Application</button>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                </form>
```

PHP File:

```
    require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';


$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$notes  = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['notes']));
$checkbox = $_POST['checker'];


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setFrom(array('From_Email' => 'My Website'))
  ->setSubject('[My_Subject from '.$name.']')
  ->setTo(array('My_Email'))
  ->setBody(
'<html>'.
'<head></head>'.
'<body>'.
'<strong>Name:</strong><br />'.
$title.' '.$name.'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Email Address:</strong><br />'.
$email.'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Phone Number:</strong><br />'.
$phone.'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Interested in:</strong><br />'.
implode('<br />', $checkbox).'<br /><br />'.
'<strong>Message:</strong><br />'.
$notes.'<br /><br />'.
'</body>'.
'</html>',
'text/html' );
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

someone suggested to me to use this jquery but i cant get it to work either.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
jQuery("#submit").click(function(){ 
    jQuery.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',  
        data: {  
            action: 'MyAjaxCallBack',
            MyParam: 'MyParamValue'
        },  
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
            alert(data);  
        },  
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
            alert(errorThrown);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

});

in the functions.php

```
 function MyAjaxCallBack()
{
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        $$key = $value;

    die('Email script will go here!');
}

// creating Ajax call for WordPress  
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxCallBack', 'MyAjaxCallBack');
add_action('wp_ajax_MyAjaxCallBack', 'MyAjaxCallBack');
```

Comment: `url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',` is error..??? don't you think it will give error..?

Comment: this [**making your wordpress talk ajax**](http://ocaoimh.ie/2008/11/01/make-your-wordpress-plugin-talk-ajax/) is a great source for using wordpress and ajax

Comment: @DipeshParmar - its included in my footer file

Comment: @Mark i mean you need to escape `'` like `url: '<?php echo admin_url(\'admin-ajax.php\');?>',` or use `"` `url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php");?>',`

Comment: oh thats what the problem was? - also where in the functions.php to i add my mailer script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved it by adding the following code
Updated:
HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="formApply"  action="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/inc/sendContact.php" name="applyForm">
                <div id="col1">
                <fieldset class="col-1">
                <div class="white info-line">Want to know more? Drop us a line and we'll get right back to you.</div>
                <label class="white text-label name" for="fname">Name:</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" tabindex="1" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label class="white text-label email" for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" class="lower" name="email" id="email"  tabindex="2"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label class="white text-label phone" for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="3" maxlength="10"/>
                <div class="white text-label checker-title" id="checkererror">I am interested in:</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Office Space" /><label for="checkbox-2-1"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Office Space</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-2" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Designated Workspace" /><label for="checkbox-2-2"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Designated Workspace</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-3" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" name="checker[]" value="Shared Space" /><label for="checkbox-2-3"></label><div class="white text-label checker">Shared Space</div>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div id="col2">
                <fieldset class="col-2">
                <label class="white text-label note-label" for="notes">Notes:</label><br/>
                <textarea name="notes" id="notes" rows="10" cols="30" class="requiredField" tabindex="4"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" class="submitted" value="true" /><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit Application</button>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                </form>
```

PHP File:

```
require( '../../../../wp-blog-header.php' );        
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';


    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname']));
    $email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
    $notes  = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['notes']));
    $checkbox = $_POST['checker'];
    $adminEmail = get_bloginfo('admin_email');

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
      ->setFrom(array('From_Email' => 'My Website'))
      ->setSubject('[My_Subject from '.$name.']')
      ->setTo(($adminEmail))
      ->setBody(
    '<html>'.
    '<head></head>'.
    '<body>'.
    '<strong>Name:</strong><br />'.
    $title.' '.$name.'<br /><br />'.
    '<strong>Email Address:</strong><br />'.
    $email.'<br /><br />'.
    '<strong>Phone Number:</strong><br />'.
    $phone.'<br /><br />'.
    '<strong>Interested in:</strong><br />'.
    implode('<br />', $checkbox).'<br /><br />'.
    '<strong>Message:</strong><br />'.
    $notes.'<br /><br />'.
    '</body>'.
    '</html>',
    'text/html' );
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
$url = home_url('/#apply');
die(header("Location: $url", true));
```